# Github Markdown's seems do not support <canvas><script>

Tags: javascript, canvas, github, markdown

I try to write js code to operate canvas，but it seems that GITHUB ignore all of them，but My Readme.md work very well on my computer editor.
Did I done something wrong?

Comment: Take a look through this https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics/ when you have an issue with markdown

Answer (score 1):

Github doesn't allow you to use JavaScript due to security reasons. If you want to publish demo on Github, you have to use dedicated platform like [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) and append link to your `README`.